ESP USB - Tinyusb Library Inclusion Problems
I am using tinyusb library for esp-32 example for tusb_serial console. It is working good when I try to integrate with my code I am getting errors with inclusion.
I have added the following dependencies in idf_component.yml
dependencies:
  espressif/esp_tinyusb: "~1.0.0"
  joltwallet/littlefs: "^1.14.4"
  ## Required IDF version
  idf:
    version: ">=4.1.0"

I am getting many errors regarding the inclusion of header files similar to this
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Computer/Desktop/xxxx/components/arduino/cores/esp32/USBCDC.cpp",
    "owner": "cpp",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "'tinyusb_add_string_descriptor' was not declared in this 
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Computer/Desktop/xxxx/components/arduino/cores/esp32/USBCDC.cpp",
    "owner": "cpp",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "'TUD_CDC_DESCRIPTOR' was not declared in this scope",
    "startLineNumber": 37,
    "startColumn": 13,
    "endLineNumber": 37,
    "endColumn": 13
}]scope",
    "startLineNumber": 34,
    "startColumn": 25,
    "endLineNumber": 34,
    "endColumn": 25
}]
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/xxxxy/components/arduino/cores/esp32/USBCDC.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++: IntelliSense",
    "code": "20",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "identifier \"TUD_CDC_DESC_LEN\" is undefined",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 35,
    "startColumn": 24,
    "endLineNumber": 35,
    "endColumn": 40
}]
[{


Please share some of your code, in a minimal reproducible example. Also you're saying that it's working good. What is working good, and when do you get errors: When you compile your code? When you add the tinyusb library? etc. Besides that, where does the error message you give come from?
